# Set default Storage::disk() for Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

Is there a way using Laravel to set my default disk to `S3`?

Throughout my project I am calling `Storage::disk('s3')` but it would be simpler if I could just call `Storage` and `S3` is the default disk.

I couldn't find anything on the documentation about doing this, maybe it's not a feature because of how Storage works over all.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to change the default in `config/filesystems.php`

Comment: @apokryfos Could you elaborate on that please? I have 3 disks in there `local, public, and s3` the driver for s3 is set to s3

Comment: @JoeScotto see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php#L16 line 16. Change it from local to s3 and you should be done.

Comment: @iH8 Thank you, that worked!

Comment: It's what @apokryfos meant, thank him ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thought and found a default configration key in `config/filesystems.php` as below,

```
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

By this means you can simply add the `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` in your .env file and then you no longer required to everytime pass the disk('s3').

It will help you too when you'll have to use local storage and then s3 when putting on production , cheers ;)